# Problem Using accented French character in search REST call

Tags: 2013, search, rest

I'm running into a problem with the search REST API. When my refinement filter parameter contains a French character I get zero results.

For example this works:

```
https://www.example.com/sites/company/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refinementfilters='TheCity:equals("Vancouver")'&sourceid='b09asdf0-05ea-4375-8asd-asdfasdfasdfasdf'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

But this doesn't work:

```
https://www.example.com/sites/company/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refinementfilters='TheCity:equals("Île-des-Soeurs")'&sourceid='b09asdf0-05ea-4375-8asd-asdfasdfasdfasdf'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode your query component. You can test it by running `encodeURIComponent` in a browser console or use any online tool like [this one](http://string-functions.com/urlencode.aspx).
So you query should be:

> https://www.example.com/sites/company/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refinementfilters='TheCity:equals("%c3%8ele-des-Soeurs")'&sourceid='b09asdf0-05ea-4375-8asd-asdfasdfasdfasdf'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'

Comment: That makes sense, but it doesn't work for me.